# Request to bold the exceptions for the "What topics can I ask about here?" section in the help center

Tags: feature-request, help-center

I've read the help center of SO many times to determine if questions are off-topic or not suitable and it wasn't until today that I realised the [on-topic points](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) 5 and 6 **have exceptions to the main point**. Let me list them out as they currently are for you

> Questions about *general computing hardware and software* are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming.

> Questions on *professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration* are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools.

Now yes they do list the exception but the **eye catching part** for me was the first bit each time. That being that "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic" And "Questions on professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration are off-topic". I did not notice the second half that if they **directly involve tools used primarily for programming.** or **directly involve programming or programming tools.** This point completely escaped my attention.

---

**So What am I suggesting?** Well when we want to emphasis **Important points** in a question or answer there seems to be a consensus that we use **bolded words**. I therefore think it would be a benefit to SO to change points 5 and 6 to read as follows

> Questions about *general computing hardware and software* are off-topic for Stack Overflow **unless they *directly involve tools* used *primarily for programming*.**

> Questions on *professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration* are off-topic for Stack Overflow **unless they *directly involve programming or programming tools*.**

In this new form we can quite clearly and quickly see that questions that initially might seem off-topic are actually on-topic. Now I'm not a reviewer myself but I'm fairly certain I've raised or seen closed a lot of questions as being off topic when they did **directly involve** programming or programming tools. I believe this is due to many users not seeing the exception immediately when looking at what's on-topic. This **isn't because they didn't read it** but rather **it didn't stand out to stick in the readers mind**. And so I believe this should be a changed feature.

Comment: I think that's fine, but the real problem, in my mind, is that the text you wish to emphasize appears nowhere in [the close dialog itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRAIo.png). Not many people switch between the help center article and the close dialog, comparing the text and so might miss out.

Comment: @HereticMonkey That's a really good point actually! That is probably an even better thing to add. It would hopefully curve down on the flagging/closing of questions that are actually valid for SO but seem off-topic